# How to select a specific class from set of classes which are implementing same interface class?

Tags: interface

How to select a specific class from set of classes which are implementing same interface class ?

Comment: Hi - what have you tried so far, and what issues have you encountered? Posting a code sample would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Phillipp, I have made 5 classes which implements same interface i.e 5 classes are lets say dog,cat,horse,lion,tiger which implements an interface named animal. Now I have to make an instance of dog which is determined by some input condition. What i have done is that i have made 5 if else condition and returned the instance of the required class. But if I have to make more than 5 such type of classes say 100 classes for different animals then i will have to write 100 if else conditions. this is the problem with my approach.

Comment: public interface Animal{

 public void eat();
}

public class Dog implements Animal{

}

public class Cat implements Animal{

}


public class Main{

 String input = "Cat";

 Animal animal = getAnimal(input);
 animal.eat();
 private Animal getAnimal(String type){
  Animal animal;
  if(type.equals("Cat")){
   animal = new Cat();
  }else if(type.equals("Dog")){
   animal = new Dog();
  }
  return animal;
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

You don't call a method directly from an interface, you call it on a reference that points to an instance of a class. Whichever class that is determines which method gets called.